# Request Camera Permission on iOS in Unity at Runtime

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, camera, ios-permissions

Our application built in Unity uses ARKit/FaceTracking on iOS.
We would like to request the Camera Permission at runtime immediately before it is used - and **not** on application startup.

**What should happen**
I use `Application.RequestUserAuthorization` immediately before the camera is used.
[According to the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.RequestUserAuthorization.html) this is supposed to trigger the permission request.

**What actually happens**
When the compiled application is started on an iOS device, the permission is requested straight away.
If the permission is denied, it appears that all further calls to `Application.RequestUserAuthorization`
instantly return (without triggering another request) and the permission remains denied.

I assume that `Application.RequestUserAuthorization` would work as expected, if the App wouldn't already request the permission on startup - but we do not actively trigger this request in our code.
So I guess here is my

**Question:**
How do I get rid of the initial Camera permission request?

What could have caused it in the first place?
For all I know, it shouldn't be the plist-string for the camera permission.
Is it already just the imports of the ArKit libraries?
If not, how can I even begin to look for a cause?

[Link to related question in unity forums](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1770441/how-can-i-prevent-our-application-to-ask-for-camer.html)

Answer (score 2):

based on my experience, ARKit/ARCore requests permission when the ARSession is enabled. so at runtime if your ARSession is disabled (i.e. on inspector before you build) the permission pop-up only appears when you enable the ARSession Object (i.e. its time to use the session)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/verifying_device_support_and_user_permission), it seems like Apple is forcing this pop-up when you use ARKit.